# Java getShopItem() and getShopUser methods

Tags: java

Hi Guys I am trying to write a method, getShopItem(), for the Shop class, that will return a pointer to a ShopItem object stored in itemsList when given the item's itemCode value, below is my attempt at coding which has been unsucessful and will not compile:

```
    public shop item.getshopitem(shopItem)

{
return this.shopitem
}
```

Shop Class:

```
public class Shop

{
   private ArrayList<Shop> shopCollection;
   private ArrayList<ShopUser> usersList;
   private ArrayList<Tool> toolsList;
   private int toolCount;
   private String toolName;
   private int power;
   private int timesBorrowed;
   private boolean rechargeable;
   private int itemCode;
   private int cost;
   private double weight;
   private boolean onLoan;
   private JFrame myFrame;
   private FileDialog fileDialogBox;
   private int mode;




    public void ReadToolData (String data) throws FileNotFoundException,NoSuchElementException

   {
       //     public void FileDialogBox() throws FileNotFoundException

       {

          if ( userSelectMode() ) // LOAD or SAVE if successful

          {

              String path = "E:/LEWIS BC 2/java project/project 1 part 3/items_all.txt";  // start browsing in root on drive E:
//               String path = "E:/LEWIS BC 2/java project/project 1 part 3/userData.txt";  // start browsing in root on drive E:

             setUpFileDialog(path);

             fileDialogBox.setVisible(true);

          }

          else

          {

             String message = "No option selected, aborting";

             String title = "Error";

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, message, title,

                                           JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

             return; // or System.exit(1)

          }



          // see what the user has selected

          String fileName = fileDialogBox.getFile();


          if ( fileName==null )

          {

             String message = "Selection cancelled by user, aborting";

             String title = "Error";

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, message, title,

                                           JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

             return; // or System.exit(2)

          }



          String directoryPath = fileDialogBox.getDirectory();

          String message = "File selected: " + fileName + "\nFolder: " + directoryPath;


          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, message, "File Selected",

                                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);



          // now create a File object

          File fileObject = new File(directoryPath, fileName);

          // note that this does NOT create an actual file -- it simply

          // creates a reference, or a "handle", for a file



          // normally would now do something useful with the File object !!

          // -- let's check if the file exists and, if so, when it was last modified

          if ( fileObject.exists() )

          {

             Date whenModified = new Date(fileObject.lastModified());

             DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();

             message = "Time file was last modified: " + df.format(whenModified);

          }

          else

             message = "File " + fileObject.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist";

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, message, "Do Something Useful",

                                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


       }

        try 
        {   // The name of the file which we will read from
            String filename = "items_all.txt";

            // Prepare to read from the file, using a Scanner object
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

           ArrayList<Tool> shops = new ArrayList<Tool>();

            // Read each line until end of file is reached
            while (in.hasNextLine())
            {
                // Read an entire line, which contains all the details for 1 account
                String line = in.nextLine();

                // Make a Scanner object to break up this line into parts
                Scanner lineBreaker = new Scanner(line);




                // 1st part is the toolCount
                try 
                {   
//                     need to put checks for empty line & comments 

                    int toolCount = lineBreaker.nextInt();

                    // 2nd part is the toolName
                    String toolName = lineBreaker.next();

                    // 3rd part is the amount of money or the Cost... 
                    int cost = lineBreaker.nextInt();

                    int total = lineBreaker.nextInt();


                }

                catch (InputMismatchException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("File not found1.");

                }

                catch (NoSuchElementException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("File not found2");

                }

            }



        }


        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");

        }   // Make an ArrayList to store all the 


        // Return the ArrayList 
//         return shops;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String test = "245.34,2456 345.2,34.12,23456 23,4";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(test);
        input.useDelimiter(",");

        while (input.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println(input.nextDouble());
        }
        System.out.println("I get to the end");

    }

    /**
     * Default Constructor for Testing
     */
     public void extractTokens(Scanner scanner ) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException

    {
        //extracts tokens from the text file
       File text = new File("E:/LEWIS BC 2/java project/project 1 part 3/items_all.txt");

       String toolName = scanner.next();
       String itemCode = scanner.next();
       String power = scanner.next();
       String timesBorrowed = scanner.next();
       String onLoan = scanner.next();
       String cost = scanner.next();
       String weight = scanner.next();

       extractTokens(scanner);

      // System.out.println(parts.get(1)); // "en"
    }


   /**
    * Creates a collection of tools to be stored in a tool list
    */
 public Shop(String toolName, int power,int timesborrowed,boolean rechargeable,int itemCode,int cost,double weight,int toolcount,boolean onLoan)
   {
      toolsList = new ArrayList<Tool>();
      toolName = new String();
      power = 0;
      timesborrowed = 0;
      rechargeable = true;
      itemCode = 001;
      cost = 100;
      weight = 0.0;
      toolCount = 0;
      onLoan = true;
   }

   /**
     * Default Constructor for Testing
     */
    public Shop()
    {
        // initialise instance variables


        toolName = "Spanner";
        itemCode = 001;
        timesBorrowed = 0;
        power = 0;
        onLoan = true;
        rechargeable = true;
        itemCode = 001;
        cost = 100;
        weight = 0.0;
        toolCount = 0;

    }
// 
//     /**
// * Creates a collection of tools to be stored in a tool list
// */
// public Shop() {
//     this.toolsList = new ArrayList<Tool>();
//     this.toolName = toolName;
//     this.power = power;
//     this.timesborrowed = timesborrowed;
//     
// 
// }
// 
// /**
//  * Default Constructor for Testing
//  */
// public Shop(){
//     // Call the previous defined constructor
//     
// }

 /**
    * Reads ElectronicToolData data from a text file 
    *
    * @param   <code>fileName</code> a <code>String</code>, the name of the 
    *          text file in which the data is stored.
    * 
    * @throws  FileNotFoundException
    */   

   //   
//     while (there are more lines in the data file )
// {
//    lineOfText = next line from scanner
//    if( line starts with // ) 
//       { // ignore }          
//    else if( line is blank )  
//       { // ignore }          
//    else
//       { code to deal with a line of ElectricTool data }
// }





       private boolean userSelectMode()

       {


          String[] options = {"LOAD", "SAVE"};

          String instr = "Select LOAD for read access, SAVE for write access";

          String title = "Select Mode";



          int button = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(myFrame, instr, title,

                                                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,

                                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,

                                                    null, options, null);

          boolean success;

          if ( button==0 )

          {

             mode = FileDialog.LOAD;

             success = true;

          }

          else if ( button==1 )

          {

             mode = FileDialog.SAVE;

             success = true;

          }

          else

             success = false;



          return success;

       }



       private void setUpFileDialog(String path)

       {

          String fileDialogTitle = null;



          if ( mode == FileDialog.LOAD )

             fileDialogTitle = "Open";

          else if ( mode == FileDialog.SAVE)

             fileDialogTitle  ="Save As";

          else

          {

             // defensive programming -- this should never happen !

             System.out.println("*** Unexpected Error -- Aborting ***");

             System.exit(1);

          }



          fileDialogBox = new FileDialog(myFrame, fileDialogTitle, mode);

          fileDialogBox.setDirectory(path);  // start browsing in folder 

                                             // corresponding to path

       }

   /**
    * Creates a tool collection and populates it using data from a text file
    */
   public Shop(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      this();
      ReadToolData(fileName);
   }

   /**
    * Adds a tool to the collection
    *
    * @param   <code>tool</code> an <code>Tool</code> object, the tool to be added
    */
   public void storeTool(Tool tool)
   {
      toolsList.add(tool);
   }

   /**
    * Shows a tool by printing it's details.  This includes
    * it's position in the collection.
    *
    * @param  <code>listPosition</code> the position of the animal
    */
   public void showTool(int listPosition)
   {
      Tool tool;
      if( listPosition < toolsList.size() )
      {
         tool = toolsList.get(listPosition);
         System.out.println("Position " + listPosition  + ": " + tool);
      }
   }

   /**
    * Returns how many tools are stored in the collection
    *
    * @return   the number of tools in the collection
    */
   public int numberOfToolls()
   {
      return toolsList.size();
   }

   /**
    * Displays all the tools in the collection
    *
    */
   public void showAllTools()
   {
      System.out.println("Shop");
      System.out.println("===");

      int listPosition = 0;
      while( listPosition<toolsList.size() )  //for each loop
      {
         showTool(listPosition);
         listPosition++;
      }
      System.out.println(listPosition + " tools shown" );    // display number of tools shown  
   }

   public void printShopiteDetails()
   {

// The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "items_all.txt";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;


        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }   

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  
            // Or we could just do this: 
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
    * Adds a shop item to the shop.
    *
    * @param   <code>shop</code> an <code>Shop</code> object, the Shop item can be added to the shop.
    */
    public void storeShopitem(Shop shop)
   {
      shopCollection.add(shop);
   }

    /**
    * Adds a shop user to the shop.
    *
    * @param   <code>shop</code> an <code>Shop</code> object, the new Shop user can be added to the shop.
    */
    public void storeShopUser(ShopUser shopUser)
   {
      usersList.add(shopUser);

   }

   /**
    * Accessor method processhireRequest
    *
    * @return shopuser and shopitem object's
    */
  public void processHireRequest(ShopItem shopItem, ShopUser shopUser) 
  {
     this.itemCode = itemCode;

}


 /**
    * Accessor method processhireRequest
    *
    * @return shopuser and shopitem object's
    */
  public void processReturnRequest(ShopItem shopItem, ShopUser shopUser) 
  {
     this.itemCode = itemCode;

}

}
```

ShopItem class:

```
public abstract class ShopItem
{
   private ArrayList<Tool> toolsList;
   Shop shop;
   private int toolCount;
   private String toolName;
   private int power;
   private int timesBorrowed;
   private boolean rechargeable;
   private int itemCode;
   private int cost;
   private double weight;
   private boolean onLoan;
   private static JFrame myFrame;
   private String Tool;
   private String ElectricTool;
   private String HandTool;
   private String Perishable;
   private String Workwear;
   private String ShopUserID;


   public void ReadToolData (String data) throws FileNotFoundException,NoSuchElementException
    {
    //    shows the directory of the text file
    File file = new File("E:/LEWIS BC 2/java project/project 1 part 3/ElectricToolData.txt");
    Scanner S = new Scanner (file);
    // prints out the data
    System.out.println();
    // prints out the
    System.out.println();
    S.nextLine();
    S.nextLine();
    S.nextLine();
    S.nextLine();
    S.nextInt ();



} 


   /**
    * Creates a collection of tools to be stored in a tool list
    */
 public ShopItem(String toolName, int power,int timesborrowed,boolean rechargeable,int itemCode,int cost,double weight,int toolcount,boolean onLoan,boolean ShopUserID)
   {
      toolsList = new ArrayList<Tool>();
      rechargeable = true;
      power = 0;
      timesborrowed = 0;
//       ShopUserID = new String();
      toolName = new String();
      itemCode = 001;
      cost = 100;
      weight = 0.0;
      toolCount = 0;
      onLoan = true;

//       ShopUserID = null;
   }

   /**
     * Default Constructor for Testing
     */
    public ShopItem()
    {
        // initialise instance variables


        rechargeable = true;
        power = 0;
        timesBorrowed = 0;
        ShopUserID = "SU002171";
        toolName = "Spanner";
        itemCode = 001;
        cost = 100;
        weight = 0.0;
        toolCount = 0;
        onLoan = true;





    }


 /**
    * Reads ElectronicToolData data from a text file 
    *
    * @param   <code>fileName</code> a <code>String</code>, the name of the 
    *          text file in which the data is stored.
    * 
    * @throws  FileNotFoundException
    */   
    public void readData(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
//   
//     while (there are more lines in the data file )
// {
//    lineOfText = next line from scanner
//    if( line starts with // ) 
//       { // ignore }          
//    else if( line is blank )  
//       { // ignore }          
//    else
//       { code to deal with a line of ElectricTool data }
// }


      myFrame = new JFrame("Testing FileDialog Box");
      myFrame.setBounds(200, 200, 800, 500);
      myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      myFrame.setVisible(true);

    { 
        FileDialog fileBox = new FileDialog(myFrame,
                      "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
      fileBox.setVisible(true);
}

    {
       File dataFile = new File(fileName);
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);

      while( scanner.hasNext() )
      {
         String info = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println(info);
      }
      scanner.close();
    }
}

 /**
     * Default Constructor for Testing
     */
    public void extractTokens(Scanner scanner) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        // extracts tokens from the scanner

        File text = new File("E:/LEWIS BC 2/java project/java project part 3/step_5_data.txt");



        String ToolName = scanner.next();
        int itemCode = scanner.nextInt();
        int cost = scanner.nextInt();
        int weight = scanner.nextInt();
        int timesBorrowed = scanner.nextInt();
        boolean rechargeable = scanner.nextBoolean();
        boolean onLoan = scanner.nextBoolean();
        String ShopUserID = scanner.next();

        extractTokens(scanner);

        // System.out.println(parts.get(1)); // "en"
    }

   /**
    * Creates a tool collection and populates it using data from a text file
    */
   public ShopItem(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      this();
      ReadToolData(fileName);
   }

   /**
    * Adds a tool to the collection
    *
    * @param   <code>tool</code> an <code>Tool</code> object, the tool to be added
    */
   public void storeTool(Tool tool)
   {
      toolsList.add(tool);
   }

   /**
    * Shows a tool by printing it's details.  This includes
    * it's position in the collection.
    *
    * @param  <code>listPosition</code> the position of the animal
    */
   public void showTool(int listPosition)
   {
      Tool tool;
      if( listPosition < toolsList.size() )
      {
         tool = toolsList.get(listPosition);
         System.out.println("Position " + listPosition  + ": " + tool);
      }
   }

   /**
    * Returns how many tools are stored in the collection
    *
    * @return   the number of tools in the collection
    */
   public int numberOfToolls()
   {
      return toolsList.size();
   }

   /**
    * Displays all the tools in the collection
    *
    */
   public void showAllTools()
   {
      System.out.println("Shop");
      System.out.println("===");

      int listPosition = 0;
      while( listPosition<toolsList.size() )  //for each loop
      {
         showTool(listPosition);
         listPosition++;
      }
      System.out.println(listPosition + " tools shown" );    // display number of tools shown  
   }

   public void printAllDetails()
   {

// The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "ElectricToolDataNew.txt";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;


        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }   

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  
            // Or we could just do this: 
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

is this above code correct and should it work??

any answers or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Should it work??` Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried it, as far as I'm aware it should work?

Comment: If you've tried it and it doesn't work, then there's your answer. I'll need more context around that code snippet to give a better answer. All I can say right now is that it doesn't look like valid java code.

Comment: still cant get it to compile but is this along the right lines?      public shop item.getshopitem(shopItem)

{
return this.shopitem
}

Comment: @user3289955, take off the "item." from your method declaration.  That's not valid Java syntax.

Comment: When posting a question asking for help with an error from some code, you really should include the error.  Generally, the java compiler gives extremely useful error messages.  A quick google search of javac errors usually turns up useful information.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public shop item.getshopitem(shopItem)
```

This isn't valid Java. You dont need to prepend the function.

```
 public ShopItem getshopitem(int shopItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you are trying to write is

```
public ShopItem getShopItem(int shopItem)
{
    return this.shopItem;
}
```

Although, in the actual method implementation, you will want to search your list of `ShopItems` for the given item code.

If you are going to be storing item codes that correspond to ShopItems, I suggest using a `HashMap` with item codes as the keys and `ShopItems` as the values.